# combine URLSession and Json Decoder AlphaVantage Overview data

Tags: swift, decode, combine, urlsession

I am trying to fetch AlphaVantage stock data by using combine, URLSession and decode it. I used a framework like the following. I used the same framework successfully fetched other AlphaVantage data such as Income statements and cash flow. however it does not work for Overview data. I could not find where the problem was. I have been struggling with this for sometime and really appreciate if someone can help.

```
import Foundation
import Combine

var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()


let pub1 = getCompOverview()
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        switch completion {
        case .finished:
            print(".sink completed")
            break
        case .failure(let anError):
            print("received error: ", anError)
        }
    }, receiveValue: { receivedValue in
        print(".sink() received \(receivedValue)")
    })
    .store(in: &subscriptions)

func getCompOverview() -> AnyPublisher<CompOverview, Error> {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo") else {
        return Fail(error: FetchError.invalidURL).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .retry(2)
        .tryMap { data, response in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200
            else {
                throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
            }
            print("fetching data size = \(data)")
            return data
        }
        .decode(type: CompOverview.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}


struct CompOverview: Codable {
    var symbol:                 String
    var name:                   String
    var description:            String
    var sector:                 String
    var industry:               String
    
    var peRatio:                String
    var pegRatio:               String
    var forwardPE:              String
    var eps:                    String
    
    var divPerShare:       String
    var divYield:          String
    var payoutRatio:            String
    
    var percentInsiders:        String
    var percentInstitutions:    String
    
    var priceToSalesRatioTTM:   String
    var marketCapitalization:   String
    var sharesOutstanding:      String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case symbol = "Symbol"
        case name = "Name"
        case description = "Description"
        case sector = "Sector"
        case industry = "Industry"
        case peRatio = "PERatio"
        case pegRatio = "PEGRatio"
        case forwardPE = "ForwardPE"
        case eps = "EPS"
        
        case divPerShare = "DividendPerShare"
        case divYield = "DividendYield"
        case payoutRatio = "PayoutRatio"
        
        case percentInsiders = "PercentInsiders"
        case percentInstitutions = "PercentInstitutions"
        
        case priceToSalesRatioTTM = "PriceToSalesRatioTTM"
        case marketCapitalization = "MarketCapitalization"
        case sharesOutstanding = "SharesOutstanding"
    }
    
}
enum FetchError: Error {
    case statusCode
    case decoding
    case invalidImage
    case invalidURL
    case other(Error)
    
    static func map(_ error: Error) -> FetchError {
        return (error as? FetchError) ?? .other(error)
    }
```

when I test the code in the playground. it printed the line in the .tryMap closure. however,  .sink did not execute.

Comment: You need to store the returned `AnyCancellable` instance that you get when subscribing, otherwise it will cancel the subscription. Also, you don't need to manually implement `decode(from:)` - just conforming to `Decodable` is enough. And also, I strongly suggest you follow the Swift naming convention and name the properties with camelCase, e.g. `var dividendPerShare: String`

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions. I added .store and still did not work. The names are the keyed names. is there a way to change the keyed names?

Comment: Yes. You can define a strategy to convert keys to camelCase, or define keys manually: Here's the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

Comment: thank you! would you please check how to make the code work?

Comment: I tried just decoding the JSON and it was failing with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS", which was probably silently swallowed by Combine. Removing a subset of properties from `CompOverview` fixes it. Not sure why this happens - maybe an internal bug with the JSON decoder